# save image to local database in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have searched all over the internet for this but i haven't really got the answer to this.

Part of the app am creating requires the user to take a photo and this photo is saved to the local database. i tried doing this as below but the method requires me to pass a bitmap (System.Windows.Media.Imaging) and the image control is well Image (System.Windows.Controls.Image)

```
public byte[] convertToByte(BitmapImage img)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                WriteableBitmap btmap = new WriteableBitmap(img.PixelWidth, img.PixelHeight);
                Extensions.SaveJpeg(btmap, ms, img.PixelWidth, img.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return ms.ToArray();
            };
        }
```

the other solution i tried assumes my image is located within the app which is not the case as it is captured by the camera

```
public byte[] convertToByte(Image img)
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
            image.UriSource = new Uri(img.Source.ToString(), UriKind.Relative);
            WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(image);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            wbmp.SaveJpeg(ms, wbmp.PixelWidth, wbmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

How can i redefine either of the methods to save the image? or is there a better way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store in db as bytes or in isolatedstorage?

Comment: Store in db as bytes

Comment: So what is the source format you need the bytes from?

Comment: an image captured by the phone camera. The image is held on the image control on the xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally figured the answer to this a while back. 
The things i've been through in the pursuit of this!

```
public Byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image img)
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(img.Source as BitmapSource);
                bmp.SaveJpeg(ms, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                Byte[] bytImage = ms.GetBuffer();
                return bytImage;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Hope anyone who gets a similar problem gets helped!